# Choropleth map layer not displaying in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers, choropleth

I have a web map showing various selectable features (point, lines, polygons) and am trying to add a choropleth layer of U.S. state data. The layer displays in the legend where I can toggle it on/off, but the color ramp data does not show, only the polygon outlines of each U.S. state. I have explored where the issue might be but cannot resolve this. Any thoughts?

I have read others with similar issues that have posted to the GIS forum and it seems the group might have insightful feedback for others.

I am including the code that I am working with below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
    <style>
        #map{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.info h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #777;
}

.legend {
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
}
.legend i {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}


    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="./data/line.js"></script>
<script src="./data/point.js"></script>
<script src="./data/polygon.js"></script>
<script src="./data/nepaldata.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
<script src="./data/statesData.js"></script>
<script>

/*===================================================
                      OSM  LAYER               
===================================================*/

    var map = L.map('map').setView([28.183303761640847,84.35412466140639], 7);
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
osm.addTo(map);

/*===================================================
                      MARKER               
===================================================*/

var singleMarker = L.marker([28.25255,83.97669]);
singleMarker.addTo(map);
var popup = singleMarker.bindPopup('This is a popup')
popup.addTo(map);

/*===================================================
                     TILE LAYER               
===================================================*/

var CartoDB_DarkMatter = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 19
});
CartoDB_DarkMatter.addTo(map);

// Google Map Layer

googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
 });
 googleStreets.addTo(map);

 // Satelite Layer
googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
   maxZoom: 20,
   subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
 });
googleSat.addTo(map);

var Stamen_Watercolor = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
 attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
subdomains: 'abcd',
minZoom: 1,
maxZoom: 16,
ext: 'jpg'
});
Stamen_Watercolor.addTo(map);


/*===================================================
                      GEOJSON               
===================================================*/

var linedata = L.geoJSON(lineJSON).addTo(map);
var pointdata = L.geoJSON(pointJSON).addTo(map);
var nepalData = L.geoJSON(nepaldataa).addTo(map);
var statesData = L.geoJSON(statesData).addTo(map)


.addTo(map);

    
var polygondata = L.geoJSON(polygonJSON,{
    onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
        layer.bindPopup('<b>This is a </b>' + feature.properties.name)
    },
    style:{
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity:1,
        color: 'green'
    }
}).addTo(map);

//Try this to add a simple statesData polygon

    

/*===================================================
                      LAYER CONTROL               
===================================================*/

var baseLayers = {
    "Satellite":googleSat,
    "Google Map":googleStreets,
    "Water Color":Stamen_Watercolor,
    "OpenStreetMap": osm,
};

   

/*==========================================================
                      TEXT AND TOGGLE BUTTONS IN LAYER BOX               
============================================================*/

var overlays = {
    "Marker": singleMarker,
    "PointData":pointdata,
    "LineData":linedata,
    "polygondata": polygondata,
    "statesData": statesData
    
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);


/*===================================================
                      SEARCH BUTTON               
===================================================*/

L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);


/*===================================================
                      Choropleth Map               
===================================================*/

L.geoJSON(statesData).addTo(map);


function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}

var geojson;
// ... our listeners
geojson = L.geoJson(statesData);

function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);

var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
        labels = [];

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);


</script>
```

Comment: With statement `var statesData = L.geoJSON(statesData)` you destroy GeoJSON `statesData`. When you try to use `statesData` again later to create choropleth layer, it of course fails because of invalid data, see error in the browser console.